# Using tablet layout folders is crashing my app

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I m making an app which has different layouts for phones and tablets. For the tablet layouts I use the folders layout-sw600, layout-sw600-land, layout-sw720 and layout-sw720-land. But when I open the app on a tablet or on an avd tablet it crashes instantly. When I run it on phones the layouts work normally. What could be the problem ? Do I have to specify something in the manifest ? Please help.
I paste the logcat errors:

```
08-16 22:30:13.124: W/dalvikvm(894): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector/com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #153: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #153: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  ... 11 more
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  ... 24 more
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894):  ... 27 more
08-16 22:30:13.694: D/dalvikvm(894): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13634K, 85% free 2497K/16280K, paused 83ms+57ms, total 370ms
08-16 22:30:17.614: I/Process(894): Sending signal. PID: 894 SIG: 9
```

This is the layout for tablets. Its all drawables.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem ?

You are running out of memory:

```
08-16 22:30:13.234: E/AndroidRuntime(894): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

This specific `OutOfMemoryError` is caused by loading a drawable resource, perhaps as a background of something in your layout.

For whatever reason, the environment you are testing on has only allocated 16MB of heap space for your process, which is rather low by modern standards. Tablets should have larger heap sizes, specifically to deal with larger background images. If you are testing on an emulator, make sure that your emulator is realistic (e.g., Android 4.x for a tablet-sized emulator image).

Comment: I also run it on a real tablet and it crashes

Comment: @mremremre1: And if it is crashing with an `OutOfMemoryError`, you are still out of memory. Note that "out of memory" could mean that there isn't a single block of memory big enough for your requested allocation. You can use MAT to try to determine where your memory is being spent. In particular, be careful when using lots of different drawable resources for large backgrounds.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the layout. Do you think its too much ?

Comment: @mremremre1: Android thinks it is too much, which is what matters.

Comment: I tried using 64 heap size and i also deleted almost every drawable from the layout making it identical to the phone layout. Still crashes.

Comment: @mremremre1: Since you can't control the heap size that way, I'm not quite certain what "tried using 64 heap size" means. As I said before, use MAT to figure out where your problem lies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35629/discussion-between-mremremre1-and-commonsware)